# cygwin curl or wget to find 404's

Tags: curl, cygwin, wget

I am looking to hit a text doc that has a bunch of quoted URL's in it to see if any of them are 404'ing. If there is a 404 I would like to get the URL that was attempted to be put into a text doc. Can anyone help me do this?

I'm looking only for the URL if it was a 404, I don't want all the other output wget --spider etc gives.

Answer (score 1):

The script

```sh
#!/bin/sh
while read
do
  echo "$REPLY"
  if wget --spider -q "$REPLY"
  then
    echo "200 OK"
  else
    echo "404 Not Found"
    echo "$REPLY" >> p404s.txt
  fi
  echo
done < test-urls.txt
```

script output

```
http://stackoverflow.com
200 OK

http://stackoverflow.com/1
404 Not Found

http://superuser.com
200 OK
```